# PL/SQL: testing functions that return Boolean value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to test a PL/SQL function that returns a Boolean value. When I try to do this using the code below I get the error:

> ORA-06550: Expression is of wrong type.

```
declare   
 v1 boolean; 
begin 
   select plsql_package.plsql_function('arg1', 'arg2') into v1 from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line('result = ' || v1);
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work like that; `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` expects *strings*, not Boolean datatype, so you have to "convert" a Boolean datatype variable's value to a string - for example, using `CASE` (as I did). Have a look at this example:

```
SQL> create or replace function plsql_function return boolean as
  2  begin
  3    return false;
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v1 boolean;
  3  begin
  4    v1 := plsql_function;
  5    dbms_output.put_line('result ' || case when v1 then 'true' else 'false' end);
  6  end;
  7  /
result false

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This misses out the initial error which is on line 4 not on line 5.

Comment: Right; I skipped it by assigning function value directly to a variable. Thank you, @MT0

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your code:

1. The `BOOLEAN` data type is a PL/SQL data type and does not exist in the SQL scope so

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION test_fn RETURN BOOLEAN IS BEGIN RETURN FALSE; END;
   /

   declare   
     v1 boolean; 
   begin 
     select test_fn() into v1 from dual;
   end;
   /
   ```

   will fail with

   ```
   ORA-06550: line 4, column 25:
   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
   ```

   because you are calling the function returning a PL/SQL only data type using SQL.

   Instead, just assign the function result to the variable without using SQL:

   ```
   declare   
     v1 boolean; 
   begin 
     v1 := test_fn();
   end;
   /
   ```
2. The both string concatenation operator `||` and `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` function do not accept a `BOOLEAN` argument.

   ```
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( FALSE );
   END;
   /
   ```

   will fail with:

   ```
   ORA-06550: line 2, column 3
   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
   ```

   and

   ```
   DECLARE
     v2 VARCHAR2(20);
   BEGIN
     v2 := 'result = ' || FALSE;
   END;
   /
   ```

   will fail with:

   ```
   ORA-06550: line 4, column 9
   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'
   ```

   Instead, you need to convert the `BOOLEAN` data type to something it does accept like a `VARCHAR2`/`CHAR`:

   ```
   DECLARE
     v1 BOOLEAN := FALSE;
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'result = ' || CASE WHEN v1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END );
   END;
   /
   ```

Comment: To add to the list, `'result = ' || v1` is also invalid because the concatenation operator accepts strings (or values that can be implicitly converted to strings), not Booleans.